# KSH: Piping stderr and stdout into variable

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I am trying to print stderr and stdout into one variable.
I want to check if rtest exists and capture the output, so i can exit the script if it isnt found.

```
checkdate=`rtest 2&>1`
```

The problem is that if i run my script stderr will still get printed on the terminal.

```
./script.ksh[26]: rtest:  not found
```

Comment: The problem is not that you do not capture the stderr of the `rtest` command - the problem is that `rtest` is not found and never runs at all. Add the full path to `rtest`, i.e. `/path/to/rtest`

Comment: That is why i want to pipe stderr to an variable. I want to exit the script if the command wasnt found.

Comment: Then use a test... `if [ ! -x rtest ]; then echo rtest not found; exit 1; fi`

Comment: This was my first try, the problem is that i will always go into the if.

Comment: That is probably because you would need to either use the full path in the `if` statement, `if [ ! -x /usr/bin/someplace/test ]` or to use @BlueMoon's `which` based solution

Comment: I used BlueMoon's soulution.
I cant really use full paths because the commands on the servers i am working with are often in different directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that the script/executable `rtest` was not found in the PATH.

Give full path (or relative) to `rtest` and then run. Note that even if `rtest` is in current directory, you'll still get the same error (unless you have the current directory in your path).

Do:

```
checkdate=$(/path/to/rtest 2&>1)
```

or

```
checkdate=$(./rtest 2&>1) # if rtest is in current directory.
```

---

To check if `rtest` is in the PATH without executing it, you can use `which` command:

`{ which rtest 2>&1 >/dev/null; } 2>&1 >/dev/null || { echo "rtest not found"; exit 1; }`

Comment: rtest isnt even supposed to run. I want to check if it exists and exit the script if it doesnt exists

Comment: But you are actually executing it. If you just to check if rtest exists without executing it then you can do: `{ which rtest 2>&1 >/dev/null; } 2>&1 >/dev/null || { echo "rtest not found"; exit 1; }`

Comment: Ok, that is exactly what i wanted. Thanks. If you could update your answer i would accept it.

Comment: Isn't it 2>&1 instead of 2&>1? The former works on ksh and bash, the latter didn't (for me).